# I can't close a Scanner object after a for loop if I use the same variable

Tags: java, for-loop, java.util.scanner, resource-leak

The program works fine but it bothers me that it gives a warning and I can't understand why!

After some tries, I realized that if I do `myObj.close()` before the first for loop it closes normally.

Before the loop? Fine. In the loop? Also fine. After the loop? `Resource leak`
I found out that using a new variable instead of reusing `i` makes the warning go away, but I still can't figure out why.

Here's part of the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean chk = false;
        
        System.out.println("ESERCIZIO 1");
        
        int num = 0;
        
        System.out.print("Inserire un numero: ");
        
        do {
            try {
                num = Integer.parseInt(myObj.nextLine());
                chk = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.print("Inserire un numero intero: ");
                chk = false;
            }
            
            if (num <= 0 && chk == true) {
                System.out.print("Inserire un numero positivo: ");
                chk = false;
            }
        } while (chk == false);
        
        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Pari");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Dispari");
        }
        
        System.out.println("\nESERCIZIO 2");
        
        int i = 0;
        
        do {
            if (i % 2 == 0 && i != 0) {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
            i += 2;
        } while ((i / 2) < 10);
        
        System.out.println("\n\nESERCIZIO 3");
        
        int n = 3;
        
        for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(n + " * " + i + " = " + (i * n));
        }
        ...
        myObj.close();
```

There are more for loops after this part, and it goes the same way.

Comment: Don't close the scanner.  When you close a scanner, it closes the underlying stream.  In this case, that is `System.in`, which means that your program won't be able to receive any input after you close the scanner.  `System.in` is a special stream; it is closed automatically by the JVM when the program terminates.  You should never close it manually.  Please note that this does not apply to other streams.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong I know, that's why I always close it at the end of my code. But why doesn't it work with the same variable?

Comment: The warning is just there to prevent you from creating a resource leak.  The compiler doesn't know what the scanner is reading from.  But you're the human being who wrote the code; you know you're just reading from `System.in`, so you can safely ignore those warnings.  Sometimes you just have to take what the IDE tells you with a grain of salt.  Also, I wouldn't close the scanner, even at the end of your code.  It's bad practice to close `System.in` because in more complex programs, it might not be so clear when you're done with it.  It's just a habit that could come back to bite you.

Comment: It should work with the same variable. Where is it not working in your code, and what error message do you get?

Comment: @NomadMaker I don't think the OP is getting an error, they are just confused about the warning messages from their IDE.  I had to re-read the question, too.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong thank you, I'll follow your advice

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong You're probably right, but I'd like to hear it from him.

Comment: @NomadMaker no errors, I can compile it and run it and it works fine. My only doubt is why using a new variable or an already used one determines whether or not it gives the resource leak warning.

Answer (score 0):

The right move is to ignore the warning.

Let me explain why intellij thinks it is appropriate to warn here, and why intellij is wrong, and why intellij can't fix the problem without 'externally annotating', which I do believe it has done for nullity typing in the core libraries, so maybe one day this problem will solve itself:

There are 3 types of resources (Things that represent streams of data and have close methods):

### A resource that is the direct representation of an OS-level handle

**These** are the ones the warning is designed for: `new FileInputStream()`, `socket.getOutputStream()`, etcetera: If you do not close these, for example because an exception occurs halfway through your processing of it, then **that OS-level handle stays open forever**, and thus if that happens a few times, best case scenario your VM is incapable of opening any file or network socket for the **rest of its existence**, or in the worst case the entire OS goes down (most OSes aren't quite that daft, fortunately). The warning is to avoid these scenarios and force you into using try-with-resources, or a try/finally block, or to upgrade your own type into one that, itself, is filter resource (see item 3 on this list).

### A resource that does not represent anything that needs closing

There are some base level resources that don't take up any system handles. For example, `new ByteArrayOutputStream()`; there is absolutely no problem whatsoever if you fail to close those. The memory they occupied goes away when the object is garbage collected, and it doesn't matter in the slightest if you closed them, or not. It doesn't hurt to close them, but if an IDE warns you, **that is an incorrect warning**.

### Filter resources

These are the problem child. Java is set up to allow you to wrap resources in filtering resource types and expects you to do this a lot. Both `BufferedReader` and `InputStreamReader` in `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))` are such filters.

In basis, filters themselves **do not** represent system resources; they do not have OS level handles and nothing bad happens if you feel to close them. However, the resource they 'wrap' (the `socket.getInputStream()` in this example) *usually does*, though this doesn't apply if it is one from the second category such as `new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArr)`. Furthermore, writing code that ensures the raw (type 1) stream is closed and which disregards the filters is *not* a resource leak but usually *is* a bug: If you write e.g.:

```
try (OutputStream raw = socket.getOutputStream()) {
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(raw, UTF_8);
    writer.send("Hello, World!\n");
}
```

Then you do not have a resource leak but you **do** have a bug: That will not actually send hello world: That's still buffered, and as you don't close the filterstream (the OutputStreamWriter), the data is never flushed.

As a consequence it's generally just simpler if you just close all the things, in reverse order.

The unfortunate part is that 'for convenience' (and this **predates** java's try-with-resources construct, which explains why this was done), filter streams are almost always **defined as per their API specification that closing them also closes the stream they are wrapping**: Closing the OutputStreamWriter will flush out all data and then also closes the socketstream you wrapped.

Herein lie all sorts of problems, because whilst you usually always want to flush, you sometimes don't want to close. If you're mixing content (first sending binary data, then some strings, then binary data again), you wrap StreamReaders/StreamWriters which you want to flush but not close.

Another example is `System.in`. You do **not** want to close that!

So, in that sense, it is 'better' if automated linting tools treat filter streams as **not** needing to be closed.

Unfortunately intellij can automatically determine based on type info alone that something is a resource (any class that implements `AutoClosable` basically has compiler/editable-checkable documentation that it can be auto-closed, which usually also means that it *must* be closed to avoid resource leaks, but not always), but it cannot determine based on type info if failure to close is a resource leak. If only there were.

The solution would be for intellij to go out of its way to manually curate a list of known types and sort them out into specific categories (type 1, type 2, or type 3), but it gets more complicated, as 'must be closed' is good to know, but you still need to know 'which code has the responsibility to do so' which is not always clear. For example, usually whomever `new X()` up a resource should close it, but e.g. `Files.newInputStream` is documented to put the responsibility to do so on the caller, even though it is not a constructor invocation and isn't itself part of a resource object (it's a static method, thus trivially it isn't part of an AutoClosable instance in the first place). This documentation cannot be extracted in an automated fashion (it should have been an annotation; unfortunately, there is no such thing. Bad API design).

This all adds up to a simple and unfortunate fact: IntelliJ is just taking a wild stab in the dark, and it guesses wrong all the time. That's not IntelliJ's fault; it's doing the best it can.

Nevertheless, it does mean that you are going to write crappy code if you are on a mission to eliminate every warning without first understanding it. In this case, once you understand that intellij's worry is that you should close the filter to avoid resource leaks and flushing issues, you can 'fix' the underlying concern by realizing that System.in should in fact *not* be closed at all, and to flush any buffered intermediate if relevant. When reading, as you are, it isn't, so that part is easy.

Then if your IDE is making it hard to pinpoint ignore such warnings, there's nothing to do but sigh and disable the entire linting category, because writing worse code to satisfy a dumb linting tool is a clear case of the tail wagging the dog. Don't be a slave to bad tools and rules, of course.